# Создать запрос в базу на Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть 2 таблицы, они связаны между собой 3ей через связь многие ко многим

```
// Таблица 1
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int Value { get;set; }
    public int Value2 { get;set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Table3> Table2 { get; set; }
}

// Таблица 2
public class Table2
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public int Name { get;set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Table3> Table1 { get; set; }
}

// Таблица 3
public class Table1Table2
{
    public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }

    public int Table2Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

Связи между ними реализованы и данные при подгрузке отображаются.

Хочу реализовать метод который бы загрузил мне 20 штук отсортированных данные из Table1, вот этот запрос.

```
_dbMainContext.Table1.OrderBy(tab=>tab.Id).Take(20).ToList();
```

Но еще мне нужно выбрать значения в фильтре из Table2

```
_dbMainContext.Table1.Where(x=>x.Table3.Any(c=>c.Table2.Name == "name1")).OrderBy(tab=>tab.Id).Take(20).ToList();
```

Но так как данных много для фильтрации, как это можно сделать по другому и можно ли такое сделать через Linq?

Comment: `_dbMainContext.Table1.Where(t=>t.Table2.Count() == 2).OrderBy(tab=>tab.Id).Take(20).ToList();` ?

Comment: @tym32167 видимо я не правильно написал, должно быть что то такое _dbMainContext.Table1.Table2.Where(x=>x.tableid == 1 && x.tableid==2).OrderBy(tab=>tab.Id).Take(20).ToList();

Comment: Как написали, такую помощь и получили :) `Но еще мне нужно что бы было связано например 2 значения из Table2.` ==> `.Where(t=>t.Table2.Count() == 2)`

Comment: @tym32167 если вы так поняли, хорошо, но слово например подразумевает что их может быть не 2 а 3 и тд, и как они должны связываться? Наверное по каким то свойствам, а вы вывели просто те строки в которые в Table2 будет 2 строки

Comment: Не надо ничего подразумевать, пишите явно что вам нужно. Если вам надо 2 и более, это будет `.Where(t=>t.Table2.Count() >= 2)`

Comment: `Table3` ? это откуда? Вы можете пояснить, что вам и как конкретно надо отфильтровать?

Comment: @tym32167 описание изменил, надеюсь станет понятнее

Comment: Я задал вопрос уже после ваших изменений

Comment: @tym32167 все в описании, 3 таблица нужна для объединения таблиц, могу в комментарии переписать все что описано выше если так будет понятнее)